# Pass data to Array of Child Components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-arrays

I have parent component and child components in my project and array of objects called from API in parent component.

- **Parent Component**

```
public Questions = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadQuestions();
}
```

```
<div *ngIf="Questions ">
   <app-child-card *ngFor="let item of Questions; index as i;" [data]="item" [index]="i" ></app-child-card>
</div>
```

- **Child Component**

```
@Input() data: any;
@Input() index: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data, this.index);
}
```

Even if my questions array is empty, child component got rendered exact three times in each try and got output `undefined undefined` in console.

Comment: Sounds strange. I can't see anything wrong with the code you have posted, my best guess is that you're array  is somehow set with three undefined items. Have you tried console logging the Questions array?

Comment: Could you post your loadQuestions() method as well?

Answer (score 4):

empty array is accepted as `true` condition, so you need to change your condition to `*ngIf="Questions.length>0"`